# Number of k-MSTs in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I am wondering if there exists a theorem similar to the [Matrix-Tree theorem of Kirchhof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem) for finding the number of [k-MSTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-minimum_spanning_tree) (Minimum Spanning Trees connecting exactly $k$ vertices in a graph). I am particularly interested in Algebraic Graph Theory and formulae similar to that of Kirchhof relating this number to the properties of the matrices associated with the super-graph [partially] spanned by these k-spanning trees. If it helps, the specific case I am interested in only concerns a connectivity graph that has binary weights on its edges and so the adjacency matrix is in the form of $\mathbf{A}\subset\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$. It goes without saying that eventually, it would be interesting to enumerate the k-MSTs, but that would go beyond the fundamental question. Any hint will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If all the edges have weight $1$, then the "$k$-MSTs" are really just $k$-vertex trees in the graph, right?

Comment: I've looked into the literature and it seems there is no such connection, or at least no one has found it yet. For example [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325467450_MTMO_an_efficient_network-centric_algorithm_for_subtree_counting_and_enumeration) the authors propose an algorithm to count the number of induced subtrees of the size $k$. It suggest that no explicit formula for this number is known.

Comment: @MishaLavrov sounds to be a good assumption; thanks! Do you happen to know a theorem about the number of such trees in relation to the algebraic properties of the graph?

Comment: @NikoWielopolski; this is very promising, thanks! I am still interested in estimating the number of such $k$-vertex trees algebraically though.

Comment: I think it would be much easier to count $(k-1)$-edge spanning forests, but here we require all $k-1$ edges to be in the same connected component, and I don't see how to do that easily.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: would it help to give a more lucid example? I am actually looking for the number of [polyomino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino) configurations in a grid (e.g. the number of pentominos in a 3 by 3 grid)

Comment: It's not that the question is unclear - I think I understand perfectly what you are asking for, I just don't think there's an easy answer. But if you elaborate on the case you want to solve, maybe there will be solutions specific to that case, so go for it! (Also, I'm not sure the polyomino question is exactly equivalent: the P pentomino, for example, is not a tree, and we'd get it twice from two different 5-vertex trees.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov: Indeed the P polyomino would be acceptable for the case I am working on, I want to see if the discrete shape (the polyomino) is connected and that it is actually a sub-graph of a square [lattice graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph), and so only verifying that there exists a tree subgraph that spans the discrete shape validates the shape. If the shape has a few more links that would be absolutely fine but it should not have a disconnected component.